# Name of an exercise machine in the gym

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Can somebody tell me what do you call in English the exercise/machine in the gym, which is in a way similar to back squat, but you do lying on your back and pushing the platform upward doing relatively the same movement as in a back squat?

Comment: What's a back squat? Is that the same as a standing squat with the barbell balanced evenly at the base of your neck? I used to perform a squat of sorts while on my back, and I called it a leg press. Hence, the apparatus would be called a leg-press machine. Actually, there are at least two such machines. One has you lying flat on your back with the weight situated directly above you, and you push the weight straight up. The other has you seated on your buttocks at an angle in such a way that you push the weight up at, say, a 45-degree angle. The latter is called an incline leg-press machine(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This machine is called a "leg press machine" of which there appear to be two varieties - inclined (to rhetorician's point) and vertical:

[image] [image]

Comment: Wow! Do you do that?

Comment: @WS2, maybe the inclined one - definitely not the vertical one - especially with all those weights! lol!